# HTML tags in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: html, google-spreadsheets

I am experiencing issues with Google Spreadsheet.
The thing is that me and my colleagues are using one spreadsheet as a table for translations, there is a column for **English** and then **German** and **French** and we have specific piece of text in each row for translation.
The thing is that we need to translate pieces of text with HTML tags like
**<span style="color:#AC0000">Translate <strong>this</strong> please</span>**
There are actually more HTML tags than that and my colleagues are not really "HTML compatible" so my question is if there is some possibility to hide those html tags for them and make them only visible to me or well any method that would make it easier. Of course there is a possibility to copy those pieces of text without HTML formatting and then just format the final translation again, but it would take an awful lot of time.

I am kindly open to all suggestions and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to remove the HTML tags with Google Spreadsheets:

- `=RegexReplace( A1, "<\/\w+>|<\w+.*?>", "" )`
  *where A1 is a cell containing HTML*

[image: Google Spreadsheet Demonstration]

**Note**

- For every HTML tag in A1, A1 must have both the open `<` and the close `>`
- The plaintext (non-HTML) should avoid **<** and **>** because it could cause false positives.

Without doing a word-for-word translation, it is unlikely that you can take the translated text and inject the original HTML programmically. This is because some words translate into multiple words and sentence structure can change when translating.